# Creating variable length fields with scapy

Tags: python, network-programming, network-protocols, scapy

I'm trying to create a new layer with scapy to build kind of specific packets. In this layer, I'm adding different fields but I don't know how to add variable length ones.

Can you please show me an example of creating a variable length field with scapy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

see [scapy build dissect](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html)

```
class FOO(Packet):
    name = "FOO"
    fields_desc = [ VarLenQField("len", None, "data"),
                    StrLenField("data", "", "len") ]

    >>> f = FOO(data="A"*129)
    >>> f.show()
    ###[ FOO ]###
      len= 0
      data=    'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
```